# Weird dropshadow in Linux Mint Cinnamon panel (VirtualBox)

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, cinnamon, panel

On my Linux Mint VM I see some weird drop shadows in my panel. What's causing this and how do I get rid of them? I tried changing themes but both dark themes ("Cinnamon" and "Linux Mint") seem to be having this issue.

[image: Menu]
[image: Programs]
[image]

---

**Versions**
Linux Mint Rebecca 17.1
Oracle VirtualBox 4.3.26

Comment: I would guess it's 3D Acceleration that might be causing that - Under Display in the VM's settings.

Comment: @DravSloan - well, that actually fixes it. But disabling it is leaving me in Software Rendering Mode, which isn't really desired.